# Display read more button after 200 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to display some text.

I want to display a read more button after 200 characters, that will display the other text of the div. And I do want to display also a read less button, when all text is displayed.

How can I achieve that?

Code:

```
<div class="reviewtekst">
<p> ALL TEXT </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inspect first length of the ALl text if it is greater than 200.

```
$('.reviewtekst').each(function() {
    var $pTag = $(this).find('p');
    if($pTag.text().length > 200){
      ....
   }
}
```

You need to copy original text and take first 200 caracters, after that append it to your div. Now you will have two p tags, one for preview other one for full text. Append links and bind click event on them to show/hide full text.
You can take a look at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cm67cun/

Comment: See my new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cm67cun/1/. I want to edit your code that it works like this. Because some classes I want to place the <a> outside the <p> class. But when clicking it does not show the content. Can you help me with fixing this?

Comment: Here is updated version https://jsfiddle.net/8cm67cun/2/ now it works fine with a tag outside the p.

Comment: Is it also possible to slowly open the content on click? So that it opens smooth?

Comment: Yes it is, just change show/hide to slideUp/slideDown, take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/4yergeLw/